# Powershell "LastWriteTime" not working

Tags: sorting, powershell-4.0, get-childitem

Is there a way to stop Powershell from sorting by default? I need to read in files from a directory and in the order which they are listed in the directory I need them to also be listed in the array (variable). Even when I use -lastwritetime on the get-childitem command, it seems to have no affect. The primary reason why I want to do this is because the files have names that are all the same except each file has a number after it like the following:
document1.doc
document2.doc
document3.doc
.....
document110.doc

The problem is if it's sorted by name, it will sort in this manner:
document1.doc
document10.doc
document111.doc
Which is horribly wrong!

Right now I have this command and it doesn't work:

```
$filesnames1 = get-childItem -name *.doc -Path c:\fileFolder\test | sort-object -LastWriteTime
```

Comment: _____________________nobody?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more along these lines.

```
$filesnames1 = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\fileFolder\test\*.doc | 
               Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
```

I don't think either of those two cmdlets have a `-LastWriteTime` parameter.

If you need only the names from those filesystem objects, you can use `($filesnames1).Name` after the code above. There are other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding Mike. What I did is put a "-filter *.pdf"  just before -path which gave me the headers. Then I piped in a  "select-object -ExpandProperty  name" to list it exactly how I needed it to. It was a little trial and error but I did eventually figure it out.

```
$filesnames1 = Get-ChildItem -filter *.doc -Path c:\fileFolder\test | 
           Sort-Object -LastWriteTime | -ExpandProperty name
```